# Writing an Activity in Xamarin and another in Android Studio released as a single apk

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm considering how to move forward with a project I have where I have to use Android Studio (because I cannot bind a given .aar in Xamarin). There's a logical break in the project where I could write half of it in Xamarin (document management) leaving the other half (document capture) in Android/java.

I wanted to see if the community considers this normal and/or possible and how to go about it. I presume that in terms of invoking fellow Activities it won't be a huge problem - that is normal (for example launching the system camera activity). I would like to know my options for bundling the 2 projects as a single apk and any specific advice before I start ...

Comment: `because I cannot bind a given .aar in Xamarin` I would recommend that you post a new question with the problems that you have are having with your Xamarin-Based binding project.

Comment: what's your problem with aar binding?

Comment: I had a plethora of errors including but not limited to half the class or function names had ` in them which wouldn't compile.

Error CS0507 'AbstractSequence.Encode(DataOutputStream)': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'CVCObject.Encode(DataOutputStream)'   
Error CS0534 'AES.AlgParamsCCM' does not implement inherited abstract member 'AlgorithmParametersSpi.EngineGetParameterSpec(Class)'  
Error CS0533 'BaseAlgorithmParameters.EngineGetParameterSpec(Class)' hides inherited abstract member 'AlgorithmParametersSpi.EngineGetParameterSpec(Class)'

Comment: It seemed the number of errors and spread of apparent causes meant the .aar was impractical to convert.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know my options for bundling the 2 projects as a single apk.

You can start with Android Studio Project (java). Start the Java project as Android Library Project in Android Studio. Archive the project to create AAR file. Once we have AAR ready we can create a Java Binding Library Project in Xamarin. You can find tutorial for the same in [Xamarin's Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/).

Java Binding Library and Android Class Library project that binds Java Library projects to C# for use in Xamarin projects. After creating Java binding Library and [resolving any binding issues](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/) , we can refer that Libray project in Xamarin.Android project. All classes, Resources in Java project will be available for use through the library project.

> There's a logical break in the project where I could write half of it in Xamarin (document management) leaving the other half (document capture) in Android/java.

If the logical break is any piece of code/ Library you have already developed in Java, you can consider binding them to C# for use in Xamarin project.

Comment: That sounds good. Is binding my only option to get a single apk?

Comment: @noelicus "Technically" you can bundle multiple apps BUT it is a manual process and not recommended. I have seen it done for side loaded apps but I believe that is would be an instant rejection from the Play store (and Amazon, etc... ). I would either develop two separate apps/apks and call Intents from one to the other and if the defendant app is not installed launch Play with the app's package id for the user to select/install OR fix the binding project (that would be my recommendation)